# dokku: Does ssh work only if public key is stored in id_rsa.pub?

Tags: docker, ssh, dokku, dokku-alt

My environment: Ubuntu server v. 18.04. with Dokku v. 0.20.3. 
Server IP is 192.168.x.y

The Problem:
From a local system I run command

```
git push dokku master
```

Now I am asked for a password:

```
dokku@192.168.x.y's password:
```

The Question:
I added a new ssh key and gave it a new name id_rsa_dokku.pub.
When adding the new ssh from id_rsa_dokku.pub to dokku server. It never works.
Only if I copy the old key from id_rsa.pub. It would work then. Why? Does ssh works only from the id_rsa.pub?

Answer (score 4):

Could finally add the key using this command on the server:

```
echo <public_key> | sudo dokku ssh-keys:add dokku
```